# Sending RSS feed to phpMyAdmin

Tags: android, rss, phpmyadmin, feed

I'm creating an Android application that requires the following:

1. Data from RSS feed gets sent to phpMyAdmin each day
2. Android app goes to phpMyAdmin and gets data from table containing RSS data
3. App makes a decision and does other processing based off the data

The goal is to get data from a website to the database, for the app to use.

I created an RSS feed from the following site [http://www.feed43.com](http://www.feed43.com/)

Now that I have my feed set up, I need to parse and send it to the table in phpMyAdmin. The thing is, how do I get the data from the feed to phpMyAdmin? After looking around on Google I've hit a lot of dead ends.

Does anyone have experience with this, or can recommend some useful pointers? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would phpMyAdmin have anything to do with this? phpMyAdmin is just a web interface for MySQL.

What you actually need is interfacing with the DBMS using SQL statements.

Comment: I have remote access to the DBMS. So I use phpMyAdmin to interface with it. I could ask for direct access. Before I do I would like to see other peoples answers to see if there is work around with phpMyAdmin. Also, could you recommend any links or syntax that could be useful for SQL statements that parse an RSS feed, in case I do get access?

Comment: The thing is, I can run SQL statements from within phpMyAdmin against the DBMS. What I really need is a way to configure either phpMyAdmin or the DBMS directly to take the RSS feed each day and insert it into a table. Am I wrong? Please let me know. Thanks

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, if you can access phpMyAdmin, you can use the same user/pw for direct DBMS access. You'll have to parse the RSS feed yourself...

Comment: @Larry yes, you are wrong. phpMyAdmin is oblivious to anything data-related. You're the one who has to lay out the data.

Comment: When you say "You'll have to parse the RSS feed yourself...", can you recomend a starting point? So you have any experience with this? After looking around on Google, I found this: http://www.nusphere.com/products/library/mysql_with_xml.pdf

Comment: It suggests using use XML::Parser; If you look at the bottom of page 9 on the link, was that the syntax you were suggesting as SQL statements? To me that does not look like SQL.

Comment: MySQL is just a data store. You have to read the data yourself (you know how to write programs, right?), parse it and put it in MySQL.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9288/discussion-between-kaod-and-larry)